# Negation using regular expressions

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a string like:

```
"<ANY>
some    STUFF   here
Obary   SEES    Obary
</ANY>
<SOME>
..."
```

Now i want to delete everething between the <> and the <> too, to get:

```
"
some    STUFF   here
Obary   SEES    Obary
..."
```

What i tried:

```
new = []
for m in re.finditer("!<[A-Z]*>|!<\/[A-Z]*>|[A-Z][a-z]+|[a-z]+", my_text):
            new.append((m.group(0)))
```

Well, now i lose "STUFF" and "SEES". How can i get rid of all `"<ASDF>"` without losing other stuff?

Comment: maybe `re.sub(r'<\w+?>', '', your_text)`?

Comment: Now i get something like: `['\n', 's', 'o', 'm', 'e', '\t',...]`. And still some `'<', '/'` in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pretty simple expression, like [`<[^>]*>`](http://regex101.com/r/qK6yA0/1), and a [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) can solve this:

```
my_text = re.sub(r"<[^>]*>", "", my_text)

# 
# some    STUFF   here
# Obary   SEES    Obary
# 
# 
# ...
```

[***Demo***](http://ideone.com/s4P4MX)

Answer (score 1):

Another option without regex (assuming we're looking at whole lines here):

```
my_text = '\n'.join([line for line in my_text if "<" not in line])
```